# Drupal 7: How do I use views to display information from the current node?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 question. I would like to display certain pieces of information from my current node using a view.

I can use views to display information from other nodes easily by setting filters and other sorting features. That's no problem. However, I want to display information from the node which is currently opened. So, for example, if I'm on a page (node: 117, title: news), I can display all the images from that page, plus captions, by creating a view.

The logic, I suppose, would be to create a view with a filter (or contextual filter) stating that the node has to equal the current node, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone have any advice? How do I instruct a view to display information from the node which is currently open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Edit the view
- Add *Content: Nid* in contextual filter
- In contextual filter options
  **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE**
  Select "*Provide default value*"
- **Type:** *Content ID from URL*

Now the default argument will be the nid of the current node.